# Write array elements based on element type

Tags: fortran, function-pointers, overloading, derived-types

What I want to accomplish is best explained by an example. In Fortran I have an array `a` of type `mixed` that holds a function pointer, an integer variable and a real variable.

```
type mixed
   procedure(), pointer, nopass :: f_ptr
   integer :: vi
   real :: vr
end type

type(mixed), dimension(10) :: a
```

The pointer `f_ptr` should point to an overloaded function that either returns the integer `vi` or the real `vr`.

```
function f_i(i)
   implicit none
   integer, intent(in) :: i
   integer :: f_i
   f_i = a(i)%vi
   return
end function

function f_r(i)
   implicit none
   integer, intent(in) :: i
   real :: f_r
   f_r = a(i)%vr
   return
end function
```

The array is initialized by for example

```
a(1)%vi = 2
a(1)%f_ptr => f_i
a(2)%vr = 3.14
a(2)%f_ptr => f_r
...
a(10)%vr = 42
a(10)%f_ptr => f_r
```

In a loop over a variable number of elements then I want to write the array elements `vi` or `vr` to an unformatted file via the function that `f_ptr` is pointing to.

```
n = 2
write(lununf) (a(j)%f_ptr, j=1,n)
```

The (readable form) output should be

```
2     3.14
```

I tried to implement this but cannot find a solution. Can it be done in some way?

Comment: When you tried to implement this, what went wrong?  And, of course, a reference to the function should be like `a(j)%f_pt(arg)`.

Comment: *"The pointer f_ptr should point to an overloaded function"* Pointers cannot point to generic function. But you don't show any overloading. You show pointing of one pointer to two incompatible functions. That is also not good.

Comment: You will have to change your approach. It is confusing, that the compiler lets you do `a(10)%f_ptr => f_r`, but it is illegal. `procedure()` means a subroutine. You can't put functions there. I am not sure what you want to do with that datastructure so it is impossible for me to offer you the right alternative. Perhaps an array of derived types which contain a `class(*)` data item? Or just a simple flag which tells whether the real or integer is valid? Both is possible, depends on your usage which you don't show.

Comment: After some thinking I managed to solve the problem :-) In the end, the issue at hand was to write unformatted data of variable length to a file using a loop over some array index. I opened an unformatted stream, determine the number of bytes to be written in the loop and write single entries depending on the type of variable (stored in another array as an int). Works perfectly! Thanks for your answers anyway.